# Sum of iid uniformly distributed random variables

Tags: probability, statistics

Recently this question appeared in the warm-up questions for the Brazilian regionals in the ICPC competition.

You have a sticker album with $N$ available slots. Every time you buy a sticker pack you get a number $A \le x \le B$ of unique stickers such that $x$ is uniformly distributed on the interval $[A, B]$. We can assume all stickers are unique, and **we never get duplicates**. We need to calculate the expected number of packages to complete the album.

The question proceeds to provide a few examples which are given as follows, where the input is given by $N$, $A$, and $B$ separated by spaces, and the output is the expected number of packages:

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| 40 0 2 | 40.33333 |
| 100 1 10 | 18.72727 |
| 30 3 3 | 10.00000 |
| 314 5 8 | 48.74556 |

My thoughts when I first saw the problem were to find the expected number of stickers per package, and then divide the number of required stickers by the expected value. In the first example this would mean:

$$
\frac{40}{\frac{2 - 0}{2}} = \frac{40}{1} = 40 
$$

Why am I wrong, and how can I really go to solve this problem?

Comment: `30 3 3` giving `10.00000` is interesting, suggesting you only want $30$ stickers and do not care whether any of them are duplicates

Comment: @Henry for the question we assume all the stickers are unique, we never get duplicate stickers

Comment: I'm assuming that you mean to say the number of stickers is uniformly distributed on the integers in $[A,B]$, so the interval would be $[A,A+1,...,B]$. An inefficient answer would be to set this up as a Markov chain with $n+1$ states $\{0,1,2,...,n\}$ and compute the expected amount of time for absorption into the state $n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost certainly a question which should be solved using [*dynamic programming*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) because it has a clear sub-structure. If you solve a lot of programming contest problems you will find this type of structure shows up all the time. Let's get into your case.

Let $X$ be the number of slots left to fill and define $E(X)$ to be the expected number of packages you will need to buy to fill $X$ slots. For convenience let $E(X) = 0$ if $X \leq 0$. The important relation is the following: If $X > 0$ then $E(X)$
\begin{equation}
    E(X) = 1 + \frac{1}{B-A+1}\sum_{j=A}^B E(X-j).
\end{equation}
I'll get into where this formula comes from below, but first I'll give you an algorithm. Note that we have $E(X) = 0$ for every $X \leq 0$ so if $X \leq 0$ just return 0. If $X > 0$ perform the following calculation

1. Create an array/list of length $N$. (Call this list $E$ and let $E(i)$ be the $i$'th entry of the list. This notational overloading is intentional!)
2. For $i = 1,...,N$ compute $$E(i) = 1 + \frac{1}{B-A+1}\sum_{j=A}^B E(i-j)$$ by accessing $E(i-j)$ by looking at the earlier entries of the array when $i - j > 0$ and taking $E(i-j) = 0$ when $i - j \leq 0$. Store the value $E(i)$.
3. Return the value in $E(N)$.

This algorithm runs quickly because each $E(i)$ **only depends on the earlier entries of the list** which we have already computed (this idea is sometimes called *memoization*). The sub-structure in this problem is that $E(i)$ can be computed from the $E(i-j)$ terms, which themselves can be computed from earlier terms.

Now let's talk about where the formula for $E(X)$ comes from (from here I assume that $X > 0$). Since $X > 0$ you must buy a package. Let $Y$ be the number of stickers in that package, so that after buying the package there are $X - Y$ remaining slots (with appropriate considerations made for negative slots). We can write the expected amount of packages we must buy to reach the end using
\begin{equation}
    E(X) = \mathbb{E}[1 + E(X-Z)] = 1 + \mathbb{E}[E(X-Z)]
\end{equation}
where the 1 is because we had to buy a package and the $E(X-Z)$ is how many slots we still need to fill. Now since $Z$ is uniformly distributed on $[A,B]$ we have for $j = A,A+1,...,B-1,B$ that
\begin{equation}
    \mathbb{P}(Z = j) = \frac{1}{B-A+1}
\end{equation}
because there are $(B-A+1)$ possible values that $Z$ can take and all have the same probability. Using this we can express the expectation explicitly
\begin{equation}
    \mathbb{E}[E(X-Z)] = \sum_{j=A}^B \mathbb{P}(Z=j)E(X-j) = \frac{1}{B-A+1}\sum_{j=A}^B E(X-j).
\end{equation}
Plugging this in above we recover the formula
$$
   E(X) = 1 +\frac{1}{B-A+1}\sum_{j=A}^B E(X-j)
$$

Comment: You may want to consider the case $A=0$ as in `40 0 2` giving `40.33333` since your final expression would have $E(X)$ on both sides and removing it gives $E(X)=1+\frac{1}{B}\left(1+\sum\limits_{j=1}^B E(X-j) \right)$.  Presumably in the context of the question you do not also have to consider cases where $A<0$ but $A+B>0$.